# EEVEE Edge detect effect

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, eevee-render-engine, edges, wireframe

I am trying to replicate an effect that one of my friends made and he was able to detect the edges of an object using Eevee all using nodes no wireframe modifiers or anything but the only way I can get close to being able to do this is with cycles. Video [here](https://vimeo.com/486242873).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As cubes (head), or scaled cubes (arms, notice the variations of the edge thickness for arms), you can compare the location to some threshold.

**Edge detection**: top line in the image below

We can take generated coordinates, and recenter them to -0.5/+0.5,

Get absolute of that.

Compare each coordinate to a threshold.

And detect the edge if more than two dimensions are above this threshold.

**Camera facing effect**: bottom line below

Compare the incoming vector to the normal using a dot product.

Keep only what is above a threshold.

Combine with the edge detection.

[image]

Comment: bless you, this worked like a charm

Comment: any way to make all the edge boxes the same size when using a mesh that isn't a cube?

Comment: If still cube based? Can try to look at the ratio object co / generated co if the origin is placed appropriatly. That should correspond to how the cube has been scaled.

Comment: ye i was saying like the arms and stuff are longer than they are wide and this makes the effect thinner there, ill try this. Thanks!